# Powershell detect USB Modem CONNECT & Disconnect events

Tags: powershell, usb, modem

At present I have a USB modem type 'Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing Device' and
tried using the following code (the first action works perfectly), from another post here, to detect the above events:

```
 $action1 = {
    Write-Host "CONNECTED"
 }
 $action2 = {
    Write-Host "DISCONNECTED"
 }

 Register-WmiEvent -Namespace root\wmi -Class MSNdis_StatusMediaConnect -Action $action1 `
     | Out-Null 
 Register-WmiEvent -Namespace root\wmi -Class MSNdis_StatusMediaDisconnect -Action $action2 `
     | Out-Null
```

The problem being that the USB device is removed before the latter event fires!
Is there a simple way that this can be fixed please?

Comment: I'm entirely unclear what you're even asking. Of course the device is removed before the event fires. How could it be any other way? The system would need to predict the future to fire the event before the device is removed.

Comment: Basically what I am after is a way to detect when such a device is unplugged.

Comment: So you mean the disconnect event isn't firing at all when the modem is unplugged? That's not clear from your question.

Comment: Correct. That is what is missing here. Sorry if I was vague about it. I used Wbemtest to check.

Comment: Finally fixed by using _SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent_ on Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration and checking TargetInstance.IPEnabled = True (or FALSE).